# Adding a line in a lmList confint plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, lme4-nlme

I guess this is a basic question but I've been looking after a solution for a long time without result.

I'm using lme4 package and I use this code :

```
library(lme4)
plot(confint(lmList(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, sleepstudy), pooled = FALSE),
     order = 1)
```

to plot confidence intervals for individual coefficients of intercept and slope:

[image]

I just want to add a vertical line (v=0) in both panels to be able to better show which CI contains 0. I've tried to use panel.abline but without success.

```
plot(confint(lmList(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, sleepstudy), pooled = FALSE),
       order = 1,
       panel=function(...){
       panel.plot(...)
       panel.abline(v=0, col="grey")
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the plot of `confint(lmList)` is a trellis object, additions to the plot can be accomplished via the `latticeExtra` package, but you have to assign the plot to an object first. The vertical line is then added to the plot object with `+ layer(panel.refline...)`.

From the `lme4` example:

```
library(lme4)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

Rxplot <- plot(confint(lmList(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, sleepstudy), pooled = FALSE))
Rxplot + layer(panel.refline(v = v, col.line = "grey"), data = list(v = 0))
```